# page not found on clicking Verification url in react Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, nodemailer, email-verification

I am trying to implement the email Verification in my web application using MERN.I am getting the Verification Url on email  But when I clicking on the verification URL I am facing this error.
[image: Error while clicking on Verification URL]

I found some solution on Stack Overflow regarding this and I followed the solution and used `encodeURIComponent()` but i didn't get any changes or fixed the problems
I compare both the result generated token and encoded Token the result attached here
[image: Code that generating token and encoding token]

The result I am getting in the console is  :
[image: Result for generating and encoded token]
After using `encodeURIComponent()` still I am getting same problem and no difference in generated and encoded token.

I also defined a correct route in the frontend for this Verification URL
[image: frontend Route for verifiying email]

But Still I am getting this Error
[image: Error]

At Last I want to say that when I remove manually all the dots(.) and hyphen(-) from the verification URL or token parameter then my components get load but then the problem is my token invalid .

I request to you please help me to solve this issue. what should i do further to solve this?

Comment: Routes in frontends help you re-render without a refresh after the initial load. Before the initial load, your webserver (whatever you are using) needs to be configured to send all these incoming requests to (presumably) some index.html using rwhat's usually called 'url rewriting'

Comment: The re-rendering doesn't happen. When i remove all the dots(.) and hyphen(-) then the components gets load fine but token become invalid because I removed some values from token.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to config the route as verify-email?token=....

Comment: yes tried in this way but same result getting.